# How to create template of map or unordered_map that takes either char or string?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, c++20, stdmap

I tried writing code that takes a .txt file as the argument, reads said file and then takes all letters(chars) of the text and all words(strings) of the text, put each of them in either a map or an unordered_map(consisting of pair<char/string and int>, for each char/string the additional number it appears), sorts them by frequency into a vector and prints the vector. When I separated both the counting function and the print function for both chars and strings it went fine, But now I want to write the print-and-sort function as a template so I can use only one function for both the strings and the chars. The main issue seems to be that I can't get both kinds of maps to fit into the print-and-sort frequency in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

    std::string sanitize_word(const std::string& word)
    {
    //Whatever this does
    }

    bool compare(const auto& a, const auto& b)
    {
       //whatever this does        }


    std::unordered_map<char,int> get_letterfrequencies(const std::string& datei)
    {//this works, get_wordfrequencies is pretty much the same, i just had to shorten it
    }

    std::unordered_map<std::string,int> get_wordfrequencies(const std::string& datei)
    {
        std::unordered_map<std::string, int> frequencies;
        std::ifstream eingabe(datei);

        if (!eingabe.is_open())
        {//irrelevant
        }
        std::string word;

        while (eingabe >> word)
        {
            std::string sanitized_word = sanitize_word(word);

            if (sanitized_word.size() > 0)
            {
                if (frequencies.count(sanitized_word))
                {
                    frequencies[sanitized_word]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    frequencies[sanitized_word] = 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {//irrelevant                                   
            }           
        }
        eingabe.close();
        return frequencies;
    }  

    template <typename Map, typename typ>
    void print_frequencies_sorted(const Map& map)
    {   
        std::vector<typ, int> mapvector(map.begin(), map.end());

        //if (!std::is_same<typ, char>() && !std::is_same<typ, std::string>())
        std::sort(mapvector.begin(), mapvector.end(), compare);            
        long double gesamt = 0;

        for(const auto& p : mapvector)
        {
            gesamt += p.second;
            double Anteil = (p.second / gesamt) * 100;
            std::cout << "[ " << p.first << ": " << p.second << "x ; also " << Anteil << "% ]" << std::endl;
        }   
        std::cout <<  " " << std::endl;
    }
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        print_frequencies_sorted(get_wordfrequencies(argv[1]));
  
        return 0;
    }
```

I tried moving the print_frequencies_sorted function in a separate function that only does those two lines, but it didn't work, I tried giving it another map but I get the "error: no matching function for call to ‘print_frequencies_sorted(std::map<char, int>&)’ " -Error every time I try to compile, having only different types instead. The errors are in the main function,
Basically I don't know how to make the print-function match the map that it gets handed.
Even without the template for the map, means handing over a direct map each time by reference, it did not work.

Comment: This is too much code for such a question. Be kind to reduce it to a [mcve].

Comment: @273K I hope this is better but since I don't know where the problem is, I can't remove a lot

Comment: I suggest templating on the key type, not on the map type.

Comment: `std::vector<Map::key_t, int>` This doesn't look like a proper type of vector. It takes an element type and (optional) an allocator. Not two element types. Anyway, why use an unordered_map and then order them later?

Comment: @BoP I changed it to a unordered map because I want to collect all strings/chars in a map, but I want it to work with both ordered as well as unordered maps. anyways, the code used to say std::vector<typ, int>, with typ being the template from above, will change this in the code

Comment: @john could you help me out on how to do that exactly? because I think I've tried it before, but if it had worked I wouldn't be asking for help, but it's not unlikely I did it wrong

Comment: this code has [lots of errors](https://godbolt.org/z/dqscr1bo6) but not the one you mentioned. Please show a [mre] with the full error message

Comment: @AlanBirtles on it, but its hard to shorten the code so that it still reprocude the "no matching function to call" error. How many lines am I allowed to use for my code?

Comment: Error messages can be a bit compicated when templates are involved. Especially if you're inexperienced, you'll have a hard time understanding those. My recommendation would be go one set of template parameters first and simply comment out the `template <typename Map, typename typ>` part and instead defining the template parameter values at namespace scope: `using Map = std::unordered_map<std::string,int>; using typ = ???;` Note that `typ` cannot be deduced from the function arguments, so you'll need to specify all the template parameters, if you keep this kind of signature...

Comment: You can of course determine the value based on the `Map` type, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem in a rather generic way.

If you look in the definition of [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) and [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), you can read, that both maps have member types "key_type" and "mapped_type".

So, if you create a template, with the Map Type as parameter, you can find out the key-type and the mapped-type. With that you can create a very generic function. It will eat and map, the `std::unordered_map` or the `std::map` with many key types and many integral value-types. So, it doesn't matter if the key is `char` or `string` and also the counter could be `int`, `unsigned_int`. or `long` or whatever.

Because we are sorting and assigning and summing, the types need to fulfill special requirements. We could used C++20 concepts, to ensure, that we get correct types. But I will not address this here.

We will implement the solution in the following way.

1. Create a type alias Pair (a "typedef"), so that we can save some typing work.
2. Define a `std::vector` of this "Pair" and use the `std::vector`s range [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (no 5) to copy all date from the map into the `std::vector`
3. Sort the vector in descending order, based on the second part of the "Pair" (the counter). Use a simple lambda for that
4. Calculate the sum of all counts using `std::accumulate` from the numeric library. Use dependent data types
5. Use a range based for loop and [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) to iterate over all entries in the vector and print out the result.

The resulting function will be ultra compact and easy to understand. Please se:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <numeric>
#include <iomanip>

std::map<char, int> mci{ {'a',1},{'b',2},{'c',3} };
std::map<std::string, int> msi{ {"aa",4},{"bb",5},{"cc",6}};
std::unordered_map<char, int> umci{ {'d',10},{'e',20},{'f',30} };
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> umsi{ {"dd",40},{"ee",50},{"ff",60} };

template <typename MapType>
void print_frequencies_sorted(const MapType& anyMap) {

    // Get the type of the pair from template element
    using Pair = std::pair < MapType::key_type, MapType::mapped_type>;

    // Copy data into map using the vectors range constructor
    std::vector<Pair> data{ anyMap.begin(), anyMap.end() };

    // Sort, descending, by frequency
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), [](const Pair& p1, const Pair& p2) {return p1.second == p2.second ? p1.first < p2.first : p1.second > p2.second; });

    // Build the sum of all frequencies
    typename MapType::mapped_type sum = std::accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0, [](const MapType::mapped_type sum, const Pair& p) { return sum + p.second; });

    // Print result
    for (const auto& [item,count] : data)
        std::cout << "[ " << item << ":\t" << count << "x ;\t also " << (double)count / (double)sum * 100.0 << "% ]" << std::endl;
}
int main() {
    print_frequencies_sorted(mci);
    print_frequencies_sorted(msi);
    print_frequencies_sorted(umci);
    print_frequencies_sorted(umsi);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second template parameter of [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is the allocator.

When using `std::vector<...> mapvector(map.begin(), map.end());` to initialize the vector, you need to use the value type of the iterator returned by `map.begin()`.

The issue with this though is that elements of a map have a const-qualified key (e.g. `std::pair<const std::string, int>`), which prevents reassignment by `std::sort`.

You need to go with pointers to the elements for this reason (or alternatively with iterators). Of course you need an appropriate compare function. Your version won't work so either introduce a suitable template or use a lambda.

```
std::unordered_map<char, int> get_letterfrequencies()
{
    // simplified logic here...
    return { {'a', 7}, {'b', 3}, {'c', 4} };
}

std::unordered_map<std::string, int> get_wordfrequencies()
{
    // simplified logic here...
    return {
            {"foo", 10},
            {"bar", 3},
            {"baz", 1},
    };
}

template <typename Map>
void print_frequencies_sorted(const Map& map)
{
    // introduce a type alias for the elements of the vector we sort
    using SortedVectorElement = typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(map.begin())>::pointer;

    // alternative relying on type value_type type alias of standard library maps
    //using SortedVectorElement = const typename Map::value_type*;

    std::vector<SortedVectorElement> mapvector;
    mapvector.resize(map.size()); // resize to the number of elements needed

    // convert the map entries elements to pointers to map entries
    std::transform(map.begin(), map.end(), mapvector.begin(), [](auto& entry) { return &entry; });

    // sort in by frequency in ascending order
    std::sort(mapvector.begin(), mapvector.end(), [](SortedVectorElement v1, SortedVectorElement v2)
        {
            return v1->second < v2->second;
        });

    long double gesamt = 0;

    for (auto p : mapvector) // no need to use references for pointers...
    {
        gesamt += p->second;
        double Anteil = (p->second / gesamt) * 100;
        std::cout << "[ " << p->first << ": " << p->second << "x ; also " << Anteil << "% ]" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << " " << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    print_frequencies_sorted(get_wordfrequencies());
    print_frequencies_sorted(get_letterfrequencies());

    return 0;
}
```

Note: One thing I didn't fix is the fact that `gesamt` does not contain the total sum of frequencies, but the sum of frequencies so far. It'll show 100% for the first entry in all cases and only produces the desired output for the last entry, at least according to my assumption.